# Does MaaS support deploying ESXi

Tags: vmware

Please help me with the following questions:

1. Is there a way in MaaS to automate the provisioning of an ESXi bare metal host?
2. What are the things we can do from MaaS wrt VWware environment (Running ESXi server and VMs)?